# ASP.NET Identity authentication signs the user out after browser refresh

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-identity, single-page-application

I'm using ASP.NET Identity for my Single Page Application authentication, everything works fine, but when I refresh the page the user signs out automatically. what is the solution for this problem? would you please introduce me a complete sample or article?

Answer (score 0):

Finally after much struggle I found the answer. I was needed to store the token to "sessionStorage" like this:

```
    var sessionToken = 'token';
    var sessionAuthenticated = 'auth';
    var sessionUser = 'user';
    var sessionIsARefresh = 'refresh';

    window.onbeforeunload = function () {
        sessionStorage.setItem(sessionAuthenticated, clientModel.authenticated());
        sessionStorage.setItem(sessionUser, clientModel.username());
        sessionStorage.setItem(sessionToken, adminModel.accessToken());
        sessionStorage.setItem(sessionIsARefresh,true);
    }

$(document).ready(function () {
    if (sessionStorage.getItem(sessionIsARefresh)) {

        adminModel.accessToken(sessionStorage.getItem(sessionToken));
        clientModel.authenticated(sessionStorage.getItem(sessionAuthenticated));
        clientModel.username(sessionStorage.getItem(sessionUser));


        getUser(clientModel.username());
        getNotificationTypes();         

    }
}
```

As I have found out according to [W3School](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) sessionStorage is more secure than cookies.